# showing projections are extreme point of a set in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Show that the set $E(H)=\left\{T \in B(H):T \geq0, ||T|| \leq 1\right\}$ for a Hilbert space H, is convex set.

prove that any projection in $B(H)$ is an extreme point of this set.

> A point $x$ of a convex set $A$ is an extreme point of $A$ if $$x=ty+(1-t)z, t\in[0,1],z,y\in A$$ then $x=y$ or $x=z$

i have done proving convex part. now if $P$ is projection and $$P=tT_1+(1-t)T_2$$. then since $||P||=1$ this gives $||tT_1+(1-t)T_2||=t||T_1||+(1-t)||T_2||=1$

from this how  can i some show that $t=0$ or $t=1$

any suggestion or any other approach .thanks in advanced.

Comment: The operator $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is a projection on $H=\mathbb{R}^2$ ($P^2 = P$), but is not an element of $E(H)$ so cannot be an extreme point of the set.

Comment: @copper.hat projections are necessarily self-adjoint in most definitions.

Comment: @s.harp: Not in any definition of a projection that I can find. Rudin, Kantorovich & Akilov, etc. (In physics a projection is often assumed orthogonal, but not generally in mathematics.)

Comment: When looking at operator algebra contexts for example a projection in a $C^*$ algebra is a self-adjoint element that squares to itself. When looking at Hilbert spaces when one says projection one almost always means [orthogonal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections), to the point that when one is interested simply in the relation $p^2=p$ this needs to be made very clear.

Comment: @s.harp: You can define it whatever way you want. I have no idea where you get the almost always from. Excepting physics texts, I have **never** seen it defined as being self adjoint. Name a single non physics text that defines it as such.

Comment: I explained the context, any book on $C^*$ algebras will define them this way, ie Murphy's book. I personally have never seen somebody talk about a projection in a Hilbert space and not mean an orthogonal projection. Since this question is about the operator algebra of a Hilbert space, this makes projections want to be self-adjoint "doubly so". Especially since the statement is false if they are not self-adjoint, and probably true if they are.

Comment: @s.harp: It makes sense with $C^*$ algebras because they are closed under adjoints, but it is not true in general no matter how much you declare it to be. If the OP wishes this to be part of the question then they need to add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p=t\,A+(1-t)\,B$, $t\notin\{0,1\}$. Since $A,B$ are positive let $a,b$ be their unique positive roots. Let $x\in \ker(p)$, you have 
$$0=\langle px,x\rangle=t\langle Ax,x\rangle +(1-t)\langle Bx,x\rangle = t \|ax\|^2+(1-t)\|bx\|^2$$
it follows $ax=bx=0$ and thus $A$ and $B$ are both zero on $\ker(p)$. The kernels of $A,B$ cannot be larger than this, for suppose $x\not\in\ker(p)$ and $Ax=0$, by subtracting an element of $\ker(p)$ we can assume $x$ to be in the subspace $p$ projects on. Then
$$\|x\|^2=\|px\|^2 = (1-t)^2\|Bx\|^2≤(1-t)^2\,\|B\|^2\|x\|^2≤(1-t)^2\|x\|^2$$
and $t=0$ must follow.

So $\ker(p)=\ker(A)=\ker(B)$. From self-adjointness follows that their images must be $\mathrm{im}(p)=\ker(p)^\perp$. So by looking at $H'=\mathrm{im}(p)$ we can assume $p=\mathbb1$.

Now we do a spectral theory argument to show that $\sigma(A)=\{1\}$ and thus $A=\mathbb1$. In the finite dimensional case it works like this: Let $x$ be an eigenvector of $A$ to eigenvalue $\lambda<1$. Then
$$x=t\,\lambda x+(1-t)Bx\implies Bx=\frac{1-\lambda t}{1-t}x$$
but $\frac{1-\lambda t}{1-t}>1$ from $\lambda<1$, contradicting $\|B\|≤1$. Now in the infinite dimensional case lets look at a resolution of identity $P_\lambda$ for $A$. If we assume that $A$ has spectrum not equal to $\{1\}$ then we must have some $\lambda<1$ so that $P_{\lambda+\epsilon}-P_\lambda\neq0$ for any $\epsilon$. For $x$ in this corresponding "eigenspace" we have $\|Ax-\lambda x\|≤\epsilon\,\|x\|$, and thus
$$x=t\,\lambda x+ t\,\tilde x+(1-t)Bx\implies Bx=\frac{1-\lambda\,t}{1-t}x-\frac{t}{1-t}\tilde x$$
here $\tilde x$ has norm $≤\epsilon \|x\|$. By taking norms we find $$\|Bx\|≥\frac{1-\lambda t}{1-t}\|x\|-\frac{t}{1-t}\epsilon\|x\|$$
and for some $\epsilon$ this will be greater than $\|x\|$, contradicting $\|B\|≤1$.